# Non duplicates mysql query php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

hey, i`m just wondering what I should do to this query to have it not return any duplicate items.

```
SELECT tag FROM tags WHERE MATCH (tag)
      AGAINST ('$sql_items' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 5
```

I`ve tried a bunch of different stuff but I can`t seem to get it to work :( I`m using php

Comment: tag field is just varchar 255 storing peoples searches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DISTINCT` is your friend :) (OR `GROUP BY`)

```
SELECT DISTINCT tag FROM tags WHERE MATCH (tag)
  AGAINST ('$sql_items' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using a `distinct` in your select clause ?

A bit like this, I'd say :

```
SELECT distinct tag 
FROM tags 
WHERE MATCH (tag)
      AGAINST ('$sql_items' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider

```
SELECT tag
FROM tags
WHERE MATCH (tag) AGAINST ('$sql_items' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
GROUP BY tag
LIMIT 5
```

This assumes you may need to select other fields from `tags`. If you just need `tag`, then `DISTINCT tag` may be all it takes.